# Windows 2019 Server Invalid Password, but RDP connection allowed

Tags: rdp, login, windows-server-2019

I run a small physical network (1 domain controller, 2 servers) on a bare-metal hosting platform.  All servers are Windows Server 2019 with Remote Desktop licensing enabled etc.

I find today that I am unable to login to the domain controller.   The RDP connection is allowed (and would tell me if my password was wrong), but when I connect to the server I see the lock screen and the title "Other User" with the message "The user name or password is incorrect.  Try again."

I can get to the same screen using KVM, but we haven't changed the passwords for several months.  Is there a known issue about this?   I normally log on using the Administrator account, so I can't go in via another route, and I need to add more users.

Can I simply restart the server and hope that this might clear it?   I have a team in India logging on to the other servers in the network on a daily basis, so I don't want to lose all Domain Controller services!

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

This might be an issue with your domain, what if you disjointed your machine from the domain and rejoin again and see if you can join normally.

Comment: A Domain Controller can't be unjoined from the domain it manages.

Comment: Thanks for the response.   Unfortunately I cannot even log in to the domain controller, so I can't take any action.   I was hoping that somebody would tell me that this has happened to them before, and that a simple reboot would fix it.   (I live in hope of a better world...!).